# How to automate Harp deployment?

Tags: deployment, build, automation, gitlab, harp

I compile my website into static HTML using Harp. I then upload the static HTML to my webserver's data directory to deploy the build. I store the markdown source in a private GitLab repository (hosted by me).

All the uploading and mucking about with Harp is a little tedious and I'd like to automate it. I would like to set things up so that as soon as I push a new commit to the GitLab repo, Harp automatically compiles and copies over the HTML files.

How can I accomplish this?

The webserver and GitLab hosts are actually both virtual hosts on the same Ubuntu machine, and I use the machine itself to run `harp compile`.

Answer (score 1):

We do this on the [harpjs.com website repo](https://github.com/harp/harpjs.com): when a commit is pushed or a pull request merged, `harp compile` is run on [Travis CI and then we publish](https://surge.sh/help/integrating-with-travis-ci) the static files to Surge.sh.

**.travis.yml**

```
language: node_js
sudo: false
node_js:
  - "4.0"
after_success:
  - npm run deploy
```

**package.json run scripts**

```
  "scripts": {
    "compile": "harp compile",
    "deploy": "npm run compile && surge ./www harpjs.com"
  }
```

Full disclosure, I am on the Harp team and we also make Surge, but I think that example in the `.travis.yml` file of the harpjs.com repo should still be applicable, even if you’re using GitLab and something other than Surge.